# unable to lookup primary campaign source in opportunity

Tags: opportunity, campaign

i have created this 'Opportunity A' & 'Campaign A', so now i would like to relate Campaign A to Opportunity A by going to Opportunity A and click on the primary Campaign Source lookup but nothing come out, i unable to search for the 'Campaign A' but i am able to search for Campaign B,C,D which is created under other record type. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was my problem. The Campaign must be 'Active' only it will appear at lookup search.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the permission of this record type, you can check your lookup search weather your record type is permitted proper permissions or not.

Comment: sorry where can i check this permission thingy?

Comment: apparently, i change the Campaign A record type to other record type and it become searchable in my Opportunity A's Primary Campaign Source lookup and then i change back to original record type and it appear! i have to change to other record type first?

Comment: Might be must have missed some thing while creating it firstly.